# Azure Table Storage - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:10002

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm developing an ASP.Net MVC & WebApi site that uses table storage in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 8. It was working fine in the development environment (when I set `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` in my web.config). I'm trying to hit **"http://localhost:80"** I have to use this and cannot use another port, have another program I am posting to my site with and it will only post to that location.

I've recently run the site and get the following error when my code gets to the following line of code: 
**CloudTable table = cloudTableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);**

Error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:10002

I've tried the following:

1) `Uninstall-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 6.1.0` and reinstalled it from NuGet

2) Restarted Windows

3) Browsed here `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.7\bin` and `ran cspack.ext` (I could not see anything else that seems to relate to storage)

It's still not running. 
Any ideas as to what I could try?

**Update:**

After getting the error above I opened up the Cloud Explorer window and could see the tables I'd created locally in dev with my code (assume this means my local storage emulator is running) but I still got the error. I then closed the window and opened it again. It spun a bit while expanding the "Storage Accounts (Classic)" but eventually showed the tables I'd created.

What is strange is that the only node in the "Cloud Explorer" window is "Storage Accounts (Classic)", I'm sure there was a list of other nodes before (i.e. WebApps etc). If anyone can help with this please can you post step by step instructions on what to do (not something like "the emulator is not running"). New to this so looking for simple instructions my gran would understand.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you talking to dev storage and it is not started...

Comment: I saw some comments about that hence me looking here: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.7\bin" but could not find anything to run.  How do I start it?

Comment: See "update" comment above. I managed to restart it by opening the "Cloud Explorer" window in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Obvious I guess, but in my MVC app I had to restart the IIS app pool to get it to connect to the emulator

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have to start the storage emulator. It is located in `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe`.

As a bonus, here's a batch script for cleaning up the emulator, as well as starting it.

```
SET emu="%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe"
%emu% stop
%emu% clear all
%emu% start
```

**UPDATE**

The difference between classic and "new" storage accounts can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619221/difference-between-new-and-classic-storage-accounts-in-azure).

> Classic storage accounts are created using existing Service Management
>   API's (the REST API stack that's been available for the past several
>   years). The newer storage accounts are created with the new Azure
>   Resource Manager (ARM) API's (which are also wrapped in PowerShell and
>   CLI now). Ultimately they provide the same resources to your apps, but
>   they're created/managed differently, and there are a few nuanced
>   differences (such as the ability to tag resources that are created via
>   ARM scripts).
>
> You can't convert a classic storage account (or any classic resource)
>   to a newer type. You don't really need to anyway, unless you're trying
>   to mix resources from classic and new, such as adding ARM-based
>   virtual machines to a classic-based virtual network, or spin up an
>   ARM-based VM from a vhd image sitting in a classic storage account
>   (and for that example, you could always just copy the vhd to a new
>   storage account). Note that, for general storage usage
>   (blobs/tables/queues), you just need the URI and the primary (or
>   secondary) key. With those, you can access your storage resources from
>   anywhere, from any VM/website/etc, regardless if you're accessing
>   storage from classic or new virtual machines, for example.

TL;DR: The difference is what API's are being used to manage the storage account. Existing API's and SDK's for downloading/uploading data to containers work with both.

Comment: Yes! Thanks :) I still can only see the "Storage Accounts (Classic)" any ideas why?

Comment: Starting the service is also detailed here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator

Comment: I also found this error when using a TimerTrigger locally - start the storage emulator and all works

Comment: More than 7 years later, still useful :)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this exact error when I am debugging my Durable function. The accepted answer helped me. Just want to point out that I was not able to start the emulator by clicking on the file. Instead, I started it by (from the link posted another user above)

- Select the Start button or press the Windows key.
- Begin typing Azure Storage Emulator.
- Select the emulator from the list of displayed applications.

After the emulator is started, the error goes away and I was able to start my durable function.

Answer (score 3):

Sharing 2 approaches which i tried when I was facing the same issue.

1. Just remove the Temp files, steps below.

> 1. Open Run (Press windows key + R)
> 2. Type %temp%
> 3. remove all the temp files or delete the Azurite folder
> 4. Restart visual studio and try debugging.

2. Kill the process which is using 10002, 10001, 10000 port

> 1. Open cmd
> 2. enter command - netstat -ano | findstr :
> 3. This will give you the process id(PID)
> 4. then enter command - tasklist /fi "pid eq "
> 5. Restart visual studio and try debugging.

Please vote if it works.

Thanks!!

Comment: deleting temp files from C:\Users\Brett\AppData\Local\Temp\Azurite and then restarting visual studio worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Install the Azurite extension in VS Code. Then click the Azurite services at the bottom of the editor window:

[image]

Once the emulators are running, you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

The latest recommendation for running local storage is to use [Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio)

It is shipped with latest Visual Studio and could be found in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator
```

or relative to place where VS is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest solution here is to install the official `Azurite` extension for VS/VSCode. Then you can run the storage emulator using `Azurite: Start Table Service` (VSCode) or the relevant command from your Windows shell (VS). See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio-code) for details.