# Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: java, azure

Good morning, I'm developing an Azure Function in Java with @TimerTrigger. When I'm trying to run it, the system throws me:

```
The listener for function 'ABC123' was unable to start.
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Do you know if it is some additional configuration on my machine or that the Azure emulator needs some additional configuration?

Thank you very much!

Comment: COuld you please your configuration file in your project?

Comment: Check out the solution in this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765141/azure-table-storage-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-act.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Table Storage - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:10002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765141/azure-table-storage-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-act)