# Azureite not starting automatically in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

I am unable to use a Blob Storage because in Visual Studio 2022 Azureite seems not to start automatically. Therefore I don't have access to databases etc.

Error I'm getting:

Azure.Core: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. System.Net.Http: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. System.Private.CoreLib: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

While starting VS I should see some information in the Output window that Azure Tools are being updated. I can't see any.

Has anybody encountered this issue already?

Answer (score 2):

Follow below steps

1. Close all the Visual Studio instances Opened (stop any Azurite processes)
2. Need to find the temp files folder of Azurite
   Find the below path on your PC
   Ex: C:\Users<Username>\AppData\Local\Temp\Azurite

Move all files into another folder ex:'Old Azurite files'
Note: Can remove if not needed

Now start Visual Studio and run the project

Referred this https://github.com/Azure/Azurite/issues/1309#issuecomment-1033390222

Comment: I just deleted the Debug.log, it had grown to huge size >1GB

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it was not something I was able to easily find a solution for. Posting this here in the hope that it helps others. I was unable to get Azurite to start automatically when running a Function project locally from VS2022, but fixed this issue by removing and re-adding the Azurite Service Dependency from the project.

After performing these steps, Azurite automatically starts now when I run the Function app locally in VS2022, with no need to manually start it via command line.:

1. Right click "Connected Services" and choose "Manage Connected Services": [image: Manage Connected Services]
2. Inside menu, disconnect "Storage Azurite emulator (Local)" if it is there. Otherwise, skip this step: [image: Disconnect Storage Azurite emulator (Local)]
3. Click the "+" to add a dependency, select "Storage Azurite emulator (Local)", and click "Next":[image: AddStorage Azurite emulator (Local)]
4. Configure the following:

- Connection string name: `AzureWebJobsStorage`
- Connection string value: `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`
- Save connection string value in (radio button): `Do not save value anywhere`.
- Note that the connection string name and value should correspond to the contents of your local.settings.json file. Click "Next".[image: Configure Azurite][image: local.settings.json]

5. Uncheck "C# code file(s)", "NuGet packages", and "Secrets store" from the summary of changes and click "Finish":[image: Summary of changes]
6. When finished, you will see something like this:
   [image: Finished configuration]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this would happen locally like Azurite Emulator stops suddenly. At that time, this type of issues occurs mostly.

To fix this, you have to [start the Azure Storage Emulator manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio#running-azurite-from-the-command-line).

It can be located in the path of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator`.

Open above path in the command prompt and run the Azurite emulator once as shown in the above link, which should clear the refusing connection issues.

Refer to this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765141/azure-table-storage-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-act) and [article](https://markgossa.com/2018/12/azure-function-listener-for-function.html) for more workarounds for the same issue.

Comment: Irrelevant - OP question is about azurite, not Azure Storage Emulator. The latter is a deprecated utility, and azurite is the recommended utility.

Answer (score 1):

First check which projects you are using in startup. Mine fails to start if using the "Configure Startup Projects | Multiple Startup Projects" options and the functions project I have (which knows to start azurite) has not already been executed.

**In this scenario:**

1. Select your Azure functions project to be "Single Startup Project"
2. F5 to debug (should now be successful in starting azurite)
3. Switch back to multiple projects startup (should work, Azurite is already
   started)

This is essentially the same as "find your azurite location and start manually", but easier from within VS. It might work properly if the multiple projects startup order is changed to start with the Azure Functions project.

Comment: The implication here is that VS2022's debug startup pipeline is slightly iffy in identifying whether it needs to start azurite for you.

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution I've come across for this to restart Windows (yes, really). Restarting VS 2022 doesn't have any effect.