# Azure Cloud Service(classic) does not autoscale with new Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-storage-queues

I deployed WorkerRole to Azure Cloud Service (classic) in new portal. With this, I also created Azure Storage account for queue.

Try to add AutoScale rule, the storage account is not listed. Tried to select `Other Resource` and put `Resource Identifier` of storage, there's no Metric name listed.

Is it by design that classic Cloud Service and new Storage account not working together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storage account *data* (e.g. blobs, queues, containers, tables) are accessible simply with account name + key. Any app can work with them.

However, to *manage/enumerate* available storage accounts, there are Classic-created and ARM-created accounts, each with different API's.

The original Azure Service Management (ASM) API doesn't know anything about ARM resources. There's a fairly good chance that, since you're deploying to a Classic cloud service, it's using ASM only and will not be able to enumerate ARM-created storage accounts.

If you create a Classic storage account (which has zero difference in functionality), you should be able to see it as an option for auto-scale.

I have a bit more details on the differences in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32620174/272109).

Answer (score 0):

At this time, it is not possible to autoscale anything based on a new "v2" storage account. It has nothing to do with the fact that you are using the classic Azure Cloud Service. I am having the same issue with using Azure App Services. In the end, I just created a classic storage account to use for the autoscaling. There is no difference in how you interact with the different types of storage accounts.