# Azure portal function app creation form does not list existing storage accounts

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am trying to create a function app using the azure portal as seen in the attached screen shot. But the drop down does not list any of the existing storage accounts (classic). Can somebody provide a pointer to the same?

Note that I have selected exisiting resource group radio button, existing storage account and hosting plan is app service plan.

[image]

Comment: Have you actually selected a subscription? It looks like it's missing in your screenshot. The UI wouldn't be able to show you existing storage accounts without knowing which subscription to pull them from.

Comment: Yes, I have selected the subscription. In screenshot its masked.

Comment: @Swapnil17 The root reason is function app does not support classic storage account, coudl you try create a new storage account(no classic)? You could check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure function is Arm mode resource, it does not support select classic storage account. You should create a storage account(Arm mode) like below.

[image]

More information about difference between new and classic storage accounts in Azure please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619221/difference-between-new-and-classic-storage-accounts-in-azure).

Comment: @Swapnil17 Does it work for you if you select arm mode storage account?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I havent tried yet. I need to check with my client if he is okay with the same. Will update here when I try it out!

Comment: @Swapnil17 OK, but I thinks it is not a browser issue.

Comment: Yes the drop down lists the storage if it ARM mode account.

Answer (score 0):

To expand another possible case, The storage account must be `general` and not `blob` storage in order to be available to the function app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using ARM for everything now, you still might not see the Storage Account you want in the list. In this case, make sure you select the correct region when creating the Function App. The Function App is published to the storage account, so the regions must match.