# Does Azure Blob Object Replication support classic storage accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/object-replication-overview) do not [specify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/object-replication-configure?tabs=portal) if object replication is supported in classic storage accounts.

I'm trying to add object replication but don't see the object replication link in the left hand menu.

Is this because my storage account is 'classic' or for some other reason?

Thanks for your help :-)

| My classic storage account | Screenshot from the docs |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not supported on Classic or even on GPv1 accounts, since the Object replication requires Change Feed - which is only supported on "GPv2 and Blob storage accounts can enable Change feed" ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-change-feed?tabs=azure-portal#enable-and-disable-the-change-feed))

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.  So GPv1 = Classic Storage?

Comment: oh, Classic is actually even older then GPv1 (General Purpose v1). So many current features will probably be lacking there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619221/difference-between-new-and-classic-storage-accounts-in-azure